# Is there a way to identify if a chrome tab is recording audio/video through the api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome has icons to identify which tab is playing/recording audio and which tab is 'casting'. Its fairly simple to use the [tabs api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) to identify which tab is playing audio (`MutedInfo`), but I can't find any equivalent for recording audio/video. This seams like something that would exist in the api, but I've had no luck finding it so far.

If anyone has an idea of where it would be in the api/how I might be able to identify which tabs are recording, that would be amazing!

[image: These indicators]

Best,
Ben

Comment: How badly do you need to do it?  If there's no proper API, you could inject script to hook all of the `getUserMedia` functions.  It's a bit nightmarish and nasty, but does work.

Comment: Ug, yea lol thats what I was hoping to avoid, I've been playing around with `getUserMedia` but its tough to deal with especially within a chrome extension. I'm gonna take a look at the chromium code to see if theres anything in there.

Comment: There's no such method in extensions API but what's "tough" specifically? AFAIK the only caveat is that you need to do it in [page context](/a/9517879).